How to show $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i X_{i+1} \rightarrow \left(EX_i \right)^2$
Suppose $X_1 , X_2, \cdots $ are i.i.d and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) < \infty$.
I want to show the following statement:
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i X_{i+1} \rightarrow \left(E[X_i]\right)^2 \ \text{in prob.}$$
I tried to use the Weak Law of Large Numbers with the definition of $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = E(X_i^2) - (EX_i)^2$, but I lost my way...
Could you please help me?

$$\frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 X_i X_{i+1} = \frac{1}{4}(X_1X_2 + X_3X_4) + \frac{1}{4}(X_2X_3 + X_4X_5)$$

@GabrielRomon Could you explain more?

Suppose $n$ is even, split the sum into two sums as indicated and apply the WLLN.

@GabrielRomon I know WLLN imples $\frac{1}{n} (X_1 + \cdots +X_n) \rightarrow EX_i$ in prob., but how can I apply it to such sums? Sorry for basic question, but I am only a beginner...

It follows directly from Birkhoff's ergodic theorem.

For $n=2k$ even, break the sum into two parts:
$$
\frac {1}{2k}\sum_{i=1}^{2k}X_iX_{i+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac 1{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{2i-1}X_{2i}+\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^kX_{2i}X_{2i+1}\right).
$$
Then apply WLLN to each of the two sums. (Note that $X_iX_{i+1}$ and $X_{i+2}X_{i+3}$ are i.i.d., and that $\mathbb E(X_iX_{i+1})=[\mathbb E(X_i)]^2$)
For $n=2k-1$ odd, note that
$$
\frac {1}{2k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2k-1}X_iX_{i+1}=\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac 12\left(\frac 1{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{2i-1}X_{2i}+\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^kX_{2i}X_{2i+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2k-1}X_{2k}X_{2k+1}
$$
and that $2k/(2k+1)\to1$ and $1/(2k+1)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.

The exact part I am struggling is to show $E(X_i X_{i+1}) = E(X_i)^2$. I know it is intuitively true, but could you explain the reason a bit more rigorously?

Oh, I forgot they are independent. Thank you!

We can actually prove the convergence in mean square. The proof is basically the same as in the i.i.d. case (computation of the variance) with an additional term that appears due to the fact that $(X_iX_{i+1})$ is not independent.
Let $Y_i=X_iX_{i+1}$. Observe that by independence, $\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_i\right]\mathbb E\left[X_{i+1}\right]=\left(\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]\right)^2$. Therefore, it suffices to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}\left(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right)=0$, or, in other words, that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{n^2}\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right])\right)^2\right]=0.
$$
Expand the square to get
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right])\right)^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[\left( Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right] \right)^2\right]
+\sum_{1\leqslant i\neq j\leqslant n}\mathbb E\left[\left( Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right] \right)\left( Y_j-\mathbb E\left[Y_j\right] \right)\right].
$$
The first term of the right hand side is $n\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$, for the second one, if $|i-j|\geqslant 2$, then $\mathbb E\left[\left( Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right] \right)\left( Y_j-\mathbb E\left[Y_j\right] \right)\right]=0$. We thus get
$$
\frac 1{n^2}\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\right])\right)^2\right]=\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_1)}{n}
+2\frac{n-1}{n^2}\mathbb E\left[\left(X_1X_2-(\mathbb E\left[X_1\right])^2\right)\left(X_2X_3-(\mathbb E\left[X_1\right])^2\right)\right].
$$
